# Which arguments (in English) are valid?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Which arguments are valid?

**Some scientists are not engineers.

Some astronauts are not engineers.

Hence, some scientists are not astronauts.**

My attempt:
$\exists$x, scientist(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$engineer(x)
$\exists$x, astronaut(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$engineer(x)
Hence, $\exists$x, scientist(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$ astronaut(x)
I feel that the argument is invalid, but I couldn't show it.

**All astronauts are scientists.

Some astronauts are engineers.

Hence, some engineers are scientists.**

My attempt:
$\forall$x, astronaut(x) $\to$ scientist(x)
$\exists$x, astronaut(x) $\wedge$ engineer(x) 
$\exists$x, engineer(x) $\wedge$ scientist(x)
I am able to prove this argument is valid if I translate the first sentence to a conjunction, instead of a conditional. But I am unsure if this is allowed.

**Some females are not mothers.

Some politicians are not females.

Hence, some politicians are not mothers.**

My attempt:
$\exists$x, female(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$mother(x)
$\exists$x, politician(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$female(x)
$\exists$x, politician(x) $\wedge$ $\sim$mother(x)
Performing specialisation (rule of inference) on the first two sentences, $\sim$mother(x) and politician(x). Then using conjunction rule of inference, I get the final sentence, so the argument is valid. But the argument is invalid!!

Much appreciated!

Comment: 2) is valid : correct. To prove it, you have to use some *proof system* (like e.g. *Natural Deduction*) or to use some "semantical" argument, for example reasoning by contradiction.

Comment: 1) is invalid : correct. To show it, find a counter-example : $\exists x (x > 1 \land \lnot odd(x))$, $\exists x (x >0 \land \lnot odd(x))$, but ...

Comment: The problem with (3) is that it would be valid if you knew "all non-females are not mothers".  But you do not know this from what is said

Comment: 3) you cannot perform "specialisation" twice with the same "eigenvariable": the assumed individual that satisfy the first premise (female and not-mother) not necessarily is the same individual that satisfy the second (politician and not-female).